# Nginx proxy cache (proxy_pass $request_uri;)

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache

I need to create proxy web using nginx.
If I access http://myweb.com/http://www.target.com/
the proxy_pass should be http://www.target.com/

Here is my configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass $request_uri;
    proxy_cache_methods GET;
    proxy_set_header   Referer   "$request_uri";
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_ignore_headers  Cache-Control;
    proxy_hide_header Pragma;
    proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header Cache-Control Public;
    proxy_cache cache;
    proxy_cache_valid  200 10h;
    proxy_cache_valid  301 302 1h;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1h;
}
```

Here is the log error

```
2013/02/05 12:58:51 [error] 2118#0: *8 invalid URL prefix in "/http://www.target.com/", client: 108.59.8.83, server: myweb.com, request: "HEAD /http://www.target.com/ HTTP/1.1", host: "myweb.com"
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you sure nginx is what you need?

Comment: I wan to create a service like images.weserv.nl
Do you know other solution?

Comment: I guess your problem is that $request_uri begins with a '/' and is not a valid URL as such. So you need to find a way to remove it. You might want to have a look at http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule. This way you can remove the '/'.

Answer (score 1):

Try the map-Module of nginx to define variable the way you want:

```
map $request_uri $proxy_pass_target { 
  default "http://myweb.com"; 
  ~^/(.+)$ $key;
}
```

Then you can use `$proxy_pass_target` in your `proxy_pass` directive instead of `$request_uri`.

Please note that I did not test if it works. Maybe you need to adjust the regex. Further documentation can be found here: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule